# Copying Files Using SuperDuper!

Tags: superduper

First time using SuperDuper and after an hour of attempting to copy files, the process is still in '1. Prepare to Copy Files'. Is this normal?

Comment: depends on how large/full the drive is. I use CCC rather than Super Duper, but the process can take several hours. I'd leave it overnight before panicking & aborting it.

Answer (score 1):

SuperDuper! has an option to repair permissions on the source volume before copying. Normally this shouldn’t take 1 hour, unless maybe you’ve never run a permissions repair in the last years and the permissions are totally screwed.

I would try this:

1. Do the permissions repair with Apple’s Disk Utility app.
2. Start SD, click on the *Options…* button, then, under the *General* tab, deselect the option *Before copy … Repair permissions on <source volume>*.
3. Start copying.